# Why is my villager's trade window disappearing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've just built a villager swapper similar to [Docm77's](http://youtu.be/9UlBKqfIS-M?t=18m), but now that I've put the villagers in the slots, I can't trade with them. Once I have swapped them down and up once, the trade window appears for a split second when I right click on the villager, but disappears immediately after. I've removed the blocks above them as well as in front of them, so they shouldn't be obstructed by anything, but to no avail.

I was able to get the trades back with one of them, by pushing him around in his cell. Is this then due to the villagers being partially inside the glass or something? How can I fix this?

Below are pictures of my setup.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Bug maybe? And what version is this? 1.8.1?

Comment: You may just need to reload the game.

Comment: I did reload the game 3 or 4 times. And yes, 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out what was causing it.

Once a villager has been "bounced" by a slime block, and is also standing on one, his trade window can glitch out like that. This is probably a 1.8/1.8.1 issue.

To fix it, I simply replaced the top slime block where they are standing with another block type (Polished Andesite) and the trades work perfectly.

Doc's design has a slime block for the top standing block, but this is unnecessary in my design because I'm not dropping my villagers in from a large height, so I really only need the slime block at the bottom.

Comment: Since this answered your question, click on the gray check on the left of your answer. The check will turn green, it will be shown to the public, and it means the answer is accepted.